# System.NotSupportedException: How to simplify the NHibernate Query?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How to simplify the below query in NHibernate?

Below is the logic to find the Max value between 3 different products and order them by the Max value.

```
IQueryable<Property> results = ISession.Get<Property>();

results =   from r in results
            let pdts = new List<decimal?> { r.Prod1.Rate, r.Prod2.Rate, r.Prod3.Rate }
            let max = pdts.Max()
            orderby max
            select r;
```

When executing it, NHibernate is throwing an error `System.NotSupportedException` with the exceptionMessage

> "exceptionMessage": "new List`1() {Void Add(System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal])([100001].Prod1.Rate), Void Add(System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal])([100001].Prod2.Rate), Void Add(System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal])([100001].Prod3.Rate)}",
>     "exceptionType": "System.NotSupportedException",

How can I simplify this query as the logic is perfect?

Comment: can you show the declaration and types of the used variables (what is `results`?)

Comment: `results` is nothing but `IQueryable<Property>`. A Property has `Prod1`, `Prod2`, `Prod3` as its properties

Comment: alright thank you, I am going to see if I can find a solution

Comment: I rewrote your query as follows and it did not throw an exception for me. `results = results.Select(r => new
                {
                    r,
                    pdts = new List<decimal?> {r.Prod1.Rate, r.Prod2.Rate, r.Prod3.Rate}
                })
                .Select(@t => new {@t, max = @t.pdts.Max()})
                .OrderBy(@t => @t.max)
                .Select(@t => @t.@t.r);` Could it be that there `results` is empty, because `ISession.Get<Property>();` returns `null` ?

Comment: Thanks. `Session.Get<Property>()` will not return `NULL`. Post it as an anwer. I'll check it and revert.

Comment: Nope. It didn't help. Still the same error. The problem is in using `new List<decimal?>` statement.

Comment: "perfect", really? Try translating this logic to SQL, that looks impossible to me. This query is indeed procedural, it has no SQL counterparts. Instead of creating a list "on the fly", you should write a join toward your three products by property row, a group by, and an order by aggregate. Or you can do as [ChoockY](/a/44586404/1178314), use ternaries which can be translated to `case when` sql statements.

Comment: @Frédéric - Thanks. C# logic is good and I don't know the same using NHibernate. Anyway will try all the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that NHibernate cannot generate the SQL from your Linq because of the List initialization is.

Try this:

```
results = from r in results
          let max = (r.Prod1.Rate >= r.Prod2.Rate && r.Prod1.Rate >= r.Prod3.Rate) ? r.Prod1.Rate
                  : (r.Prod2.Rate >= r.Prod1.Rate && r.Prod2.Rate >= r.Prod3.Rate) ? r.Prod2.Rate
                  : r.Prod3.Rate
          orderby max
          select r;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to achieve with your solution